# "got succeeded"?

Tags: passive-voice, auxiliary-verbs, transitivity

"I worked hard and later on I got **succeeded**" ?

Question:  Someone told me that I cannot use the word *succeeded* with *got*.  Is this correct?

Comment: Your informant is correct. *Succeed* is an intransitive verb and does not take an object, so it cannot be cast in the passive -- which is the sense of this use of *get*.

Comment: Actually context is very important here. "Succeed" can also mean "take the place of someone/replace." The sentence on its own may mean: "[Although] I worked hard, later on, somebody replaced me. [I feel that this is very unfair]." We need more context. On its own, it's fine. Unless the OP wants to say "[Because] I worked hard, later on, I was successful", in which case this is wrong

Comment: @Au101: would you regard *him* in "I succeeded him" as the *direct* object of a transitive verb "to succeed"?

Comment: @TRomano: Yes, I think so. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/succeed, http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/succeed, http://www.thefreedictionary.com/succeeded. It is equivalent, surely, to "I replaced him", "I superseded him", etc. I have no problem with "Mikoyan was succeeded by Nicolai Podgorny" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_leaders_of_the_Soviet_Union). Mikoyan got succeeded. It may not be how I would put it, but I would certainly accept it.

Comment: @Au101.  I'm wondering why "got succeeded" sounds unnatural to me (even when I understand the context) but "was succeeded" doesn't. Oddly, I would have no problem with "They got followed by the store detective."

Comment: @TRomano I agree with you that "got succeeded" is a little unusual. It may be (pure speculation) that the use of "succeeded" in this context is quite high brow and formal, while the use of "got" is quite colloquial. To be fair to all concerned, I would not recommend that a learner use this specific phrasing. However, I think it's actually perfectly parsable and if I ever saw it, I would not think of it as a mistake. So if the OP used this in the context I gave - or heard it in this context - then I would say: it's fine it makes sense, but maybe it should be put differently next time.

Comment: I worked hard and later on I got success or sucessed,which is the verb form of success to be used in the past

Comment: @user122708 hi! What do you mean by _Question-Some one told me_ ? Can you tell where else you asked, if it is not a secret? :-)

Answer (score 1):

The person who told you is correct. The verb *to get* is often used to convey a passive meaning and replaces the verb *to be* that you would normally use in that case.

Now, since the verb *to succeed* is not a transitive verb (you cannot succeed *someone/something*), it cannot be used in the passive sense here. So, you cannot say *I got succeeded*. What is correct is *I succeeded*.

Verbs that are transitive can be used with *to get*, allow me to illustrate with another example:

> The man *got killed* in the car accident.

But this would be incorrect, since *to die* is not transitive:

> *He *got died* in the car accident.

Since the verb *to die* is intransitive, it does not take an object and be turned into a passive. Correct would be:

> He *died* in the car accident.

I hope this makes the difference clear.

Answer (score 0):

True, "got succeeded" is not correct. Instead you could say

> I worked hard and later succeeded.

or

> I worked hard and later had success.

Answer (score 0):

> "I worked hard and later on I got succeeded" ?

*To be succeeded by X* means "to be replaced by X because X is better or newer."

The *by X* may be omitted if it is unknown, or obvious from context.

What @Sander says about *get* replacing *be* is correct.

So if the speaker really meant this, then it makes sense (assuming that it's obvious from context who/what succeeded the speaker):

> "I worked hard and later on I was succeeded"